# they can be the subjects of sentences vs the subject of a sentence

Tags: grammar

I would like to ask which of the following sentences is grammatically correct.

1. They (nouns) can be the subjects of sentences
2. They (nouns) can be the subject of a sentence

Shouldn't we use the first sentence as "they" is a plural pronoun and "subjects of sentences" is also plural? So each noun can be the subject of a sentence (or sentences). The second sentence seems to mean that all nouns can be the subject of the same sentence. However, I see the second sentence much more often, so I am confused.

Comment: Neither strikes me as obviously wrong, but instead of (2) I think _It (a noun) can be the subject of a sentence_ would be more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English can be fairly loose with number concordance, especially with "notional" agreement. In a strict sense, you are correct: multiple nouns can be multiple subjects of multiple sentences. However, colloquially (and even in some formal contexts) people will often use a singular predicative expression (such as "the subject of a sentence") with a plural subject (such as "they").

The concept is a bit similar to that of pronouns that have a distributive meaning, such as "everyone". See this question, for example: ["Everyone put on his coats" or "everyone put on their coats"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141209/everyone-put-on-his-coats-or-everyone-put-on-their-coats/141220).

By the way, your second example sentence would be correct if you were [*mentioning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) the word "they" (instead of *using* it):

> "They" can be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: Thank you, it is clearer to me now. Am I right to assume "they can be the subject of a sentence" having the same meaning as "Each of them can be the subject of a sentence"? "They" in this context has a distributive meaning (each member is considered separately).

Comment: Yes, it would have the same meaning as "each of them can be the subject of a sentence", which nobody would object to on grammatical grounds.